# how to programming serial port of ios without jail break

Tags: ios, iphone, serial-port

As the title says
i've searched for this on Google for about a week.
lots of instruction and articles about programming serial port of iOS.
but all of them have one precondition:
your iOS has to be jail broken first！
Actually i want to develop a app enabled audio peripheral which connected to iDevice(iPhone, iTouch,iPad) by the serial port and ship it by the App Store, where the user can download the App there! At this scenario, i can't tell my user to jailbreak their iPhone in order to use my App.May be lots of them don't even know what jailbreak is.
Help me!

Thanks

David zhu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to join the [Apple MFI program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/) in order to obtain this level of access to the iPhone/iPad hardware.  Alternatively, investigate the use of Bluetooth Low Energy - this does not require MFI program membership